# Can't add libraries from maven to my gradle project in Intellij

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, javafx, dependency-management

I'm working first time on a JavaFX and I'm not able to add a library to my Gradle project in Intellij.

I tried many solution that I found on the internet but I wasn't able to solve my problem.

The library that I'm tring to install is [com.itextpdf/itext7-core/7.0.4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itext7-core/7.0.4).

I tried by adding the implementation code line in the gradle build project but it didn't solve my problem. I tried also to add the library from the project setting in intellij and even after the library was downloaded to the "lib" folder I cound't use the library's classes.

If anyone knows a tutorial or can describe a step by step guide to do so it would be very helpful.

I uploaded all the files in [github](https://github.com/dcfrenci/AppProject_Preventivo) and I removed all the testing that I did.

Here the build gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.12'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.25.0'
}

group 'com.preventivoApp'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.9.1'
}

sourceCompatibility = '17'
targetCompatibility = '17'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'com.preventivoapp.appproject_preventivo'
    mainClass = 'com.preventivoapp.appproject_preventivo.HelloApplication'
}

javafx {
    version = '17.0.2'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.controlsfx:controlsfx:11.1.2')

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jlink {
    imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'app'
    }
}

jlinkZip {
    group = 'distribution'
}
```

Comment: Well, the solution is to put `implementation('com.itextpdf:itext7-core:8.0.0')` inside the `dependencies` block (also note I used version 8.0.0; it's typically good to use the latest versions of libraries as possible, especially since the version you linked to mentions 4 _known_ security vulnerabilities). You would then refresh the project in IntelliJ if the IDE doesn't do so automatically. If this isn't working for you, please describe the problem you're having.

Comment: I tried to go this way but even after I added the line that you suggest in the build file and refreshed the project I can't use the classes in the library.
With "refresh the project" you mean clicking the icon that appear on the top right of the screen right?